# Why Dota Reborn cant "CreateContex()" on OpenGL?

Tags: 64-bit, intel, opengl

When I run `Reborn` it just show:

```
CreateContext():
Failed to create a OpenGL context.

Quad 6400
4GB ram

Linux diver 3.16.0-49-generic #65~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Sep 9 10:03:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux


OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) G41
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-47e18a5 2015-09-16 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 11.1.0-devel (git-47e18a5 2015-09-16 trusty-oibaf-ppa)
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel {already cool}
add-apt-repository ppaibaf/graphics-drivers {up mesa from 10.3.1 to 11.1}
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages suggest you to install a PPA with newer drivers. I did some googling and found this: https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers, which does indeed contain Mesa 11.1.

The procedure would be:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

If that doesn't work, you can revert your changes with:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I already did it. I upgraded the mesa from 10.3.1 because with my IntelG41 I read the 11.1 fixed some stuffs. But the screen kept the same: 

'ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/nostra/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.'
and
'Failed to create an OpenGL context.
Dongle firmware /home/nostra/.local/share/Steam/linux64/../controller_base/d0ggle.bin loaded, version 1435869091.
Attempting to create OpenGL context: v3.3 (Core profile)...failed.
Attempting to create OpenGL context: v3.1 (Core profile)...failed.'